# CSS Text Align - Why is my paragraph text not aligning as I need it to, while headlines do?

Tags: html, css

I need the text on this page to mirror how the headlines directly above each section are laid out (3 items, 1st left, 2nd center and 3rd right align).

Can anyone explain why this hasn't worked for me?

```css
/** General Settings **/

.heading {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px;
}
.subheading {
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px;
}
.content {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  padding: 0px;
}
.title1 {
  text-align: left;
}
.explanation1 {
  font-size: 1em;
  text-align: left;
  max-width: 300px;
  min-height: 100px;
}
.title2 {
  text-align: center;
}
.explanation2 {
  font-size: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 300px;
  min-height: 100px;
}
.title3 {
  text-align: right;
}
.explanation3 {
  font-size: 1em;
  text-align: right;
  max-width: 300px;
  min-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="heading">
  <h1> Page Heading </h1>
</div>
<div class="subheading">
  <h2> Page Subheading </h2>
</div>

<div class="title1">
  <h4> Reason 1 </h4> 
</div>

<div class="explanation1">
  <p>Reason 1 Text</p>
</div>

<div class="title2">
  <h4> Reason 2 </h4>
</div>

<div class="explanation2">
  <p>Reason 2 Text</p>
</div>

<div class="title3">
  <h4> Reason 3 </h4>
</div>

<div class="explanation3">
  <p>Reason 3 Text</p>
</div>
```

Definitely a noob question but if someone could explain where I went wrong I'd much appreciate it!

Comment: Voting to close as typo ... You have a `max-width` for those containers of `300px` ..

Comment: not sure why you want to put max-width to the paragraph, but if that's intentionally, you need to put the max-width to the header also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do something like this:

```
.heading {
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
text-align: center;
padding:0px;
}

.subheading {
font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
text-align: center;
padding:0px;
}

.content {
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
padding:0px;
}

.title1{
text-align: left
;
}

.explanation1 {
font-size: 1em;
text-align: left;
}

.title2 {
text-align: center;
}



.explanation2 {
font-size: 1em;
text-align: center;

}

.title3 {
text-align: right;
}

.explanation3 {
font-size: 1em;
text-align: right;

}
```

and remove the width/height limits. Tested here: https://jsfiddle.net/9v5824kp/

Comment: Okay, great thanks!!

In this case, how do I use formatting to make the text fit into specifically sized boxes with a background etc? I wanted to do that next, but if it won't work with the max width and height added, it'll just display the real text across the page.

I'll mark your answer as correct :)

Comment: It's going to take some work, but you would have to use margins to position your text. I'd look into the bootstrap framework if your looking to create fixed with boxes. Best of luck!

Comment: Hm okay, that's the second time someone has mentioned Bootstrap to me, so I guess I should really start to get to grips with it.

Thanks!

Comment: It's a great framework that really helps with layouts. Definitely familiarize yourself with it, and other frameworks like it..

Answer (score 1):

Your `explination` classes have `max-width` while your heading classes do not. Usually this is causing your paragraph blocks to be narrower than the page.

Answer (score 0):

this problem sometimes happen with me
if you use localhost that take time to refresh the page on web server (http) if the files in your pc try to open it with chrome like file:///C:/file/index.html in your browser